# Phone reboots when I connect it to my PC via USB

Tags: usb, boot-loop, reboot, system-freeze

I have a Medion P5015 and I've tried rooting it with Kingroot and Kingoroot together with the PC and Android versions but to no avail. Now when I try to connect my phone to my PC with the provided data cable, the screen freezes as soon as I plug it in. Soft buttons & hard buttons do nothing. After a few seconds, it reboots to the boot screen but goes to a black screen and goes back to the boot screen, and goes on.

When I unplug it during this stage, it cuts off then I have to manually power it on with the power button, quite absurd if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I find that rooting and such causes unforeseen problems. I am trying to learn to keep everything stock and update when they are available. It is very hard sometimes to resist temptation. But usually, there are negative results down the road. I would reset my phone to the factory by going to Settings > Backup & reset > Factory data reset > Reset phone. It will pop up confirmation. Click yes and the phone will then reboot and continue the Reset from recovery mode.

Comment: Thanks for the response, since I can't connect my phone to my pc to perform a backup on my applications along with there data is there something I can do?